# Complicated data

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance, query-performance

I have a requirement i got from my father. He gave me a table and wanted me to digitalis it. So that he can the system can do all the dirty jobs for him ( that's why there are developers in the world, isn't it). The table like this (i created it in HTML + jQuery) 
[image: Crop specification form]
and i managed to store it to mySQL data base and the it looks like this.
[image: landuse is name of the data base]
Crop: the final table
Char: altitiude, mean_temperature .... are all characteristics
s: s1,s2,s3,n
range: for each data there may be multiple ranges

but i am notconvinced this is the right way to do it! I know this because i can't write a query to retrieve the data with a convincing query.

My Question
 How should i structure the database so that

1. The data can be stored in time and storage optimized manner
2. The data can be retrieved in timely manner using as short as possible query.

**EDITED**
mySQL DDL

```
--
-- Database: `landuse`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `landuse` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `landuse`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `char`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `char` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `s1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `s2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `s3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `n` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=271 ;

--
-- RELATIONS FOR TABLE `char`:
--   `n`
--       `s` -> `id`
--   `s1`
--       `s` -> `id`
--   `s2`
--       `s` -> `id`
--   `s3`
--       `s` -> `id`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `crop`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `crop` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `altitude` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mean_temperature` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LGP` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rainfall_during_LGP` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `soil_drainage` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `effective_soil_depth` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stones_rock_outcrops` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `slope_angle` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;

--
-- RELATIONS FOR TABLE `crop`:
--   `LGP`
--       `char` -> `id`
--   `altitude`
--       `char` -> `id`
--   `effective_soil_depth`
--       `char` -> `id`
--   `mean_temperature`
--       `char` -> `id`
--   `rainfall_during_LGP`
--       `char` -> `id`
--   `slope_angle`
--       `char` -> `id`
--   `soil_drainage`
--       `char` -> `id`
--   `stones_rock_outcrops`
--       `char` -> `id`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `land`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `land` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `altitude` float NOT NULL,
  `mean_temperature` float NOT NULL,
  `LGP` float NOT NULL,
  `rainfall_during_LGP` float NOT NULL,
  `soil_drainage` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `effective_soil_depth` float NOT NULL,
  `stones_rock_outcrops` float NOT NULL,
  `slope_angle` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `range`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `range` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `min` float NOT NULL,
  `max` float NOT NULL,
  `const` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- RELATIONS FOR TABLE `range`:
--   `id`
--       `s` -> `id`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `s`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `s` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1170 ;
```

The following is the php code that inserts the data from the view! (the view sends an json data)

PHP

```
$crop = $_REQUEST["crop"];

$crop_data = json_decode($crop);
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=landuse', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
    $dbh->beginTransaction();
//    foreach($dbh->query("SELECT * FROM s") as $row){
//        print_r($row);
//    }
    $insert_range = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `range`(id, `min`, `max`)VALUES (:s_id,:min,:max);");
    $insert_range_drainage = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `range`(id, const)values(:s_id,:const);");
    $insert_s = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO s(id, type)values(NULL,:type);");
    $insert_character = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `char` (`id`, `s1`, `s2`, `s3`, `n`) VALUES (NULL, :s1, :s2, :s3, :n);");
    $insert_crop = $dbh->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO `crop` (`id`, `name`, `altitude`, `mean_temperature`, `LGP`, `rainfall_during_LGP`, `soil_drainage`, `effective_soil_depth`, `stones_rock_outcrops`, `slope_angle`)
              VALUES (NULL,:name,:altitude,:mean_temperature,:LGP,:rainfall_during_LGP, :soil_drainage, :effective_soil_depth, :stones_rock_outcrops, :slope_angle)");
    $altitude=0;
    $mean_temperature=0;
    $LGP=0;
    $rainfall_during_LGP=0;
    $soil_drainage=0;
    $effective_soil_depth=0;
    $stones_rock_outcrops=0;
    $slope_angle=0;
    foreach ($crop_data as $key => $c) {
        if($key=="name"){
            break;
        }
        //for each characteristics
        //$key is the name of the current characteristics
        //$c is the array of the values (s1,s2,s3,n)

        //the following are to hold the id's of s that are stored
        $s1 = 0;
        $s2 = 0;
        $s3 = 0;
        $n = 0;
        foreach ($c as $s => $val) {
            //for each s
            //save it to the data base
            $insert_s->bindParam(":type", $s);
            if (!$insert_s->execute()) {
                $dbh->rollBack();
                echo '<div style="background-color: red">s not inserted</div>';
            };
            //get the id of the saved 's'
            $s_id = 0;
            foreach ($dbh->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as last_id;") as $row) {
                $s_id = $row["last_id"];
            }

            //set the respective field for each s
            if($s=="s1"){
                $s1=$s_id;
                echo "S1=".$s_id;
            }elseif($s=="s2"){
                $s2=$s_id;
                echo "S2=".$s_id;
            }elseif($s=="s3"){
                $s3=$s_id;
                echo "S3=".$s_id;
            }elseif($s=="n"){
                $n=$s_id;
                echo "N=".$s_id;
            }

            foreach ($val as $range) {
                //for each range
                //save the range in the data base.
                if ($key == "soil_drainage") {
                    $insert_range_drainage->bindParam(":s_id", $s_id);
                    $insert_range_drainage->bindParam(":const", $range->min);

                    if (!$insert_range_drainage->execute()){
                        $dbh->rollBack();
                        echo '<div style="background-color: red">range not inserted (drainage)</div>';
                    };
                }else{
                    $insert_range->bindParam(":s_id", $s_id);
                    $insert_range->bindParam(":min", $range->min);
                    $insert_range->bindParam(":max", $range->max);

                    if (!$insert_range->execute()) {
                        $dbh->rollBack();
                        echo '<div style="background-color: red">range not inserted</div>';
                    };
                }
            }
        }
        //insert characteristics to the database
        $insert_character->bindParam(":s1",$s1);
        $insert_character->bindParam(":s2",$s2);
        $insert_character->bindParam(":s3",$s3);
        $insert_character->bindParam(":n",$n);

        if (!$insert_character->execute()) {
            $dbh->rollBack();
            echo '<div style="background-color: red">character not inserted</div>';
        };
        //Get the id of the current character saved
        $character_id = 0;
        foreach ($dbh->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as last_id;") as $row) {
            $character_id = $row["last_id"];
        }

        if($key=="altitude"){
            $altitude=$character_id;
        }elseif($key=="mean_temperature"){
            $mean_temperature=$character_id;
        }elseif($key=="LGP"){
            $LGP=$character_id;
        }elseif($key=="rainfall_during_LGP"){
            $rainfall_during_LGP=$character_id;
        }elseif($key=="soil_drainage"){
            $soil_drainage=$character_id;
        }elseif($key=="effective_soil_depth"){
            $effective_soil_depth=$character_id;
        }elseif($key=="stones_rock_outcrops"){
            $stones_rock_outcrops=$character_id;
        }elseif($key=="slope_angle"){
            $slope_angle=$character_id;
        }

    }
    //Insert the crop
    $insert_crop->bindParam(":name",$crop_data->name);
    $insert_crop->bindParam(":altitude",$altitude);
    $insert_crop->bindParam(":mean_temperature",$mean_temperature);
    $insert_crop->bindParam(":LGP",$LGP);
    $insert_crop->bindParam(":rainfall_during_LGP",$rainfall_during_LGP);
    $insert_crop->bindParam(":soil_drainage",$soil_drainage);
    $insert_crop->bindParam(":effective_soil_depth",$effective_soil_depth);
    $insert_crop->bindParam(":stones_rock_outcrops",$stones_rock_outcrops);
    $insert_crop->bindParam(":slope_angle",$slope_angle);
echo 'dfghjkl;'.$crop_data->name;
    if (!$insert_crop->execute()) {
        $dbh->rollBack();
        print_r($insert_crop->errorInfo());
        echo '<div style="background-color: red">crop not inserted</div>';
    };
    $dbh->commit();
} catch (PDOException $x) {
    echo '<br/>' . $x->getMessage();
}
```

here is a sample json data

```
{  
   "altitude":{  
      "s1":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "s2":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "s3":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "n":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ]
   },
   "mean_temperature":{  
      "s1":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "s2":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         },
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         },
         {  
            "min":"0.01",
            "max":"0.01"
         }
      ],
      "s3":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "n":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ]
   },
   "LGP":{  
      "s1":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "s2":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "s3":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         },
         {  
            "min":"200",
            "max":"300"
         }
      ],
      "n":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ]
   },
   "rainfall_during_LGP":{  
      "s1":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "s2":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         },
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "s3":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "n":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ]
   },
   "soil_drainage":{  
      "s1":[  
         {  
            "min":"MW"
         }
      ],
      "s2":[  
         {  
            "min":"W"
         }
      ],
      "s3":[  
         {  
            "min":"MW-W"
         },
         {  
            "min":"MW-I"
         }
      ],
      "n":[  
         {  
            "min":"I"
         }
      ]
   },
   "effective_soil_depth":{  
      "s1":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "s2":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "s3":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "n":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ]
   },
   "stones_rock_outcrops":{  
      "s1":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "s2":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "s3":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         },
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "n":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ]
   },
   "slope_angle":{  
      "s1":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "s2":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "s3":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         },
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ],
      "n":[  
         {  
            "min":"100",
            "max":"100"
         }
      ]
   },
   "name":"Maize"
}
```

Comment: Post SHOW CREATE TABLE crop (&c.)\G and some sample data (INSERT INTO TABLE crop (&c.) VALUES (...). Your diagram is somewhat confusing.

Comment: would the php that does it be okey?

Comment: Not really - just use the mysql client (mysql > SHOW CREATE TABLE crop\G). I want to be able to create the tables myself - with the PHP code, I'll have to extract the SQL (DDL and DML).

Comment: I added the mysql DDL as generated by phpmyadmin and also added the php that is currently responsible for inserting the data! I have also added JSON that is processed by the php

Comment: Thanks for the CREATE TABLE statements. Now, could you do a mysqldump of the data and either post it here or somewhere on the net for download? I can't afford the time to learn PHP/JSON to answer questions here - I have enough languages on my plate :-) See [here](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/) (and links within) about asking questions. I do notice that your tables have no FOREIGN KEYs - that is not what your diagram appears to want to say.

Comment: the sql dump doesn't show the foreign keys either! What is wrong with it?

Comment: please check this for the dump! [link](http://txt.do/o5zv)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16921/discussion-between-amanuel-nega-and-verace).

Answer (score 1):

A problem could be you are trying to store the measurements in a single table that you are 'navigating' to via a suitability table. It makes sense but you may want to consider separate tables

```
crop (id*, name)

altitude (crop_id*, suitability_id*, min, max)

temperature (crop_id*, suitability_id*, min, max)

...

slope_angle (crop_id*, suitability_id*, min, max)

suitability (id*, name)
```

from your form, it looks like a measurement may have multiple ranges for the same suitability? you may need to add a sequence like attribute or further normalise if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I've put this in an "answer", because the system is complaining about chatting here, and you can't chat privately since your reputation is insufficient IIRC. We can "chat" by you editing your question and me editing my answer.

You wrote:

> the sql dump doesn't show the foreign keys either! What is wrong with
>   it?

The FOREIGN KEYs will be visible in the SHOW CREATE TABLE statements anyway. On one level, there's nothing "wrong" - you just haven't declared FOREIGN KEYs.

As I said, your diagram appears to suggest that you want them and on first inspection, I would say that they would be a good idea for your system (or any database system), to ensure that RI (Referential Integrity) is enforced at the database level. Have seen the dump - that's good, however we need to have the relationships between the tables determined - and only you can do that - I'd just be guessing.

Your crop table seems to be wrong - you have mean temperatures going up to 256 (in what units, I don't know), but even if it's Fahrenheit, that's above the boiling point of water (212). I would also urge you to use metric.

Comment: I know what i did wrong now! I created the tables using phpmyadmin and i created internal relations instead of foreign keys! And for the units, i didn't put any validation on the input. I wanted to finish up with the core part first. 
And i tried to add a foreign key just now, but it seems that i can't add two foreign keys on two different columns that reference the same table. Example s1,s2,s3,n of the char table all need to reference id of s. and MySQL is refusing to add the foreign keys.